# load_model with a metric

Tags: keras, keras-2

I save a model with a metric I defined as it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59347770/2613663) .
Were they do the following:

```
def get_lr_metric(optimizer):
    def lr(y_true, y_pred):
        return optimizer.lr
    return lr

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
lr_metric = get_lr_metric(optimizer)

model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer,
    metrics=['accuracy', lr_metric],
    loss='mean_absolute_error', 
    )
```

It works great.
However, when I try to load this module:

```
keras.models.load_model(model_path, custom_objects = {'get_lr_metric': get_lr_metric})
```

I get:
*ValueError: Unable to restore custom object of type _tf_keras_metric currently. Please make sure that the layer implements `get_config`and `from_config` when saving. In addition, please use the `custom_objects` arg when calling `load_model()`.*

Trying the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61790464/2613663):

```
def get_lr_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1

keras.models.load_model(model_path, custom_objects = {'get_lr_metric': get_lr_metric})
```

shows the same error message.

I use tensorflow 2.3.0 (keras 2.4.0) with Python 3.8 on Windows 10.

**How should I load the model?**

Comment: Same problem. Have you found an answer in the mean time?